# Pandas doesn't assign values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wrote a function that creates a table of periods given the comparison of a value from a series as well as a specific minimum duration.

Now I recently cleaned up my environment and somehow the same function doesn't assign values anymore as it did before.
However, it still creates a dataframe of the right shape, it just doesn't assign values and I can't figure out why.

Previous output:

[image]

Current output:

[image]

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import dataframe_image as dfi

# getting the last periods of increasing interest rates (Federal Funds Effective MONTHLY Rate) from 1965 onwards
fed_rates = web.DataReader("FEDFUNDS", "fred", 1965)
fed_rates.set_index(pd.to_datetime(fed_rates.index.date), inplace=True)

# test for empty values
print(fed_rates.index.isna().sum())

def period_df(start, duration, fed_rates=fed_rates):
    fed_rates = fed_rates[fed_rates.index >= start]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Start", "Last"])
    df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [None, None, None]

    period = 0
    j = 0

    for i in range(0, len(fed_rates) - 1):
        if (fed_rates.iloc[i + 1]["FEDFUNDS"] <= fed_rates.iloc[i]["FEDFUNDS"]) and (
            i - j >= duration
        ):
            df.loc[period]["Last"] = datetime.strftime(fed_rates.index[i], "%Y-%m-%d")
            period += 1
            if (fed_rates.index[-1] - fed_rates.index[i]).days >= 365:
                df.loc[len(df)] = [None, None, None]
                j = i
        elif (fed_rates.iloc[i + 1]["FEDFUNDS"] <= fed_rates.iloc[i]["FEDFUNDS"]) and (
            i - j < duration
        ):
            df.iloc[period]["Name"] = "Period " + str(period + 1)
            df.loc[period]["Start"] = datetime.strftime(fed_rates.index[i], "%Y-%m-%d")
            j = i

    # add last date
    df.loc[period]["Last"] = datetime.strftime(fed_rates.index[-1], "%Y-%m-%d")

    # add duration column
    df["Duration"] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df["Last"]) - pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])
    ) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")

    # export df as image
    dfi.export(
        df.style.set_properties(
            **{"background-color": "white", "color": "black", "border-color": "#948b8b"}
        ),
        "periods" + start + ".png",
    )
    return df


period_df(start="1995", duration=9)
```

Comment: Are you getting a warning named `SettingWithCopyWarning` when you run your code?

Comment: Yes, but this wasn't a problem before. Do I need to revert pandas to some other version?

Comment: Well, that's strange. But I believe the cause of your problem now are your `df.loc[row][col]` (or `iloc`) assignments. When you do it that way, `df.loc[row]` executes first and returns a copy of the row, so any changes are made on a copy and not on the original data. Try using `df.loc[row, col]` or `df.at[row, col]` for assignments and see if that helps

Comment: That actually fixed it. So simple, thanks. But also weird that it worked before

Comment: Yeah, definitely weird. I'll post an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas the `loc`/`iloc` operations, when they are not setting anything, just return a copy of the data.

When you do something along the lines of `df.loc[row][col] = value`, it may look like the `loc` operation setting something, but this "assignment" happen in two stages:

1. First, `df.loc[row]` retrieves a copy of the relevant row
2. Then, the copy's `col` is set to `value`

You can avoid this by passing `row` and `col` to `loc`/`iloc` or even use `at`/`iat`:

```py
df.loc[row, col] = value
df.at[row, col] = value
```